# Python3: Edit dictionary class instance variable

Tags: python-3.x, class, dictionary, instance-variables, keyerror

```
class myClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.myClassDict = {}

    def ADD_DictPair(self, Value, Key):
        #Per ShadowRanger's Solution (Solved)
        #self.myClassDict[Value] = Key #Wrong Code
        self.myClassDict[Key] = Value  #Correct Code

    def get_myDict(self):
        return self.myClassDict


InstanceOfmyClass = myClass()
InstanceOfmyClass.ADD_DictPair("Value1","Key1")
InstanceOfmyClass.ADD_DictPair("Value2","Key3")
InstanceOfmyClass.ADD_DictPair("Value3","Key3")

print(InstanceOfmyClass.get_myDict()["Key1"])

    Desired Output: "Value1"

    Error: print(InstanceOfmyClass.get_myDict()["Key1"])
           KeyError: 'Key1'
```

Python3 in Windows // Sublime Text 3

My goal is to interact with the dictionary through it's class method to Add, Call, and Edit values.

Comment: You made all your strings with "Value" in the keys, and vice versa, then tried to use the dictionary as if the strings with "Key" were the keys. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: You're right, thanks! How silly of me!

Comment: On a side note - you reallly should check your naming conventions - it looks like you run all your variable-name parts capitalization through a randomizer before getting to the name. The PEP 8 document has usefull suggestions for pretty looking code.

Comment: And on another side note, you call your dict "classDict' - but you are aware it is bound to the instance, and each instance will have its own dict with this code, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def ADD_DictPair(self, Value, Key):
    #Per ShadowRanger's Solution (Solved)
    #self.myClassDict[Value] = Key #Wrong Code
    self.myClassDict[Key] = Value  #Correct Code
```